# Regex works in regexr, but not if I filter content

Tags: functions, filters, content, regex

I want to filter the content of everypost and add classes to my links depending on certain conditions. At the moment I just want to filter all href attributes from the content and change them.

```
add_filter( 'the_content' , 'add_link_classes' );

function add_link_classes( $content ) {

    $url_regex = "/\href\=\"(http|https)\:\/\/.+?(?=[\"])\"/";

    preg_match_all( $url_regex, $content, $matches );

    var_dump( $matches );

    return $content;
}
```

var_dump returns this:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> array(0) { } }
```

But as you can see, the same expression works as expected on [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/3ctmq).

Comment: you probably need to do more escaping to take into account how php parses strings

Comment: You should use single quoted strings for regexs in PHP, and only backslash as necessary: `'/href="(http|https):\/\/.+?"/'`

Comment: @bonger That was the right answer. I notice now, that the question is a little bit off-topic. But if you post that as an answer, I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Coolio, wilco...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per comments, it's best to use single quoted strings for regexs in PHP (then only backslash and single quote are special), and only backslash as necessary, eg in this case

```
$url_regex = '/href="(http|https):\/\/.+?"/';
```

(leaving out the positive lookahead which isn't needed here).